# Sémantique, suffixation et synonymie du « supportérisme » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes, suffixes, sport

« (...) [considère le sociologue français du **supportérisme** Nicolas Hourcade](https://www.lapresse.ca/sports/soccer/201904/13/01-5222064-les-actes-racistes-se-multiplient-dans-les-stades-deurope.php) [...] »

Peut-on donner une définition du terme en précisant le sens du suffixe dans *[supportér](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/supporter/2)[isme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-isme)*, identifier sommairement l'origine du mot et donner un synonyme  le [cas échéant](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3582) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La définition du TLFi est pour le moins floue, et l’exemple cité est d’une rare incorporalité :

> [**SUPPORTERISME**](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/supporterisme) <sup>subst. masc.,sports.</sup> Action de supporter. *Le « supporterisme » est un comportement social qui engage l'individu, y compris dans son corps : lui aussi, il « fait le déplacement ». Il y a onze bons joueurs (face à onze méchants) sur le terrain, mais ils sont aussi des milliers dans les tribunes* (Le Monde aujourd'hui, col. 4, 2-3 juin 1985, p. II, col. 6).

On cerne mal les tenants et aboutissants du concept en y étant introduit de la sorte.

Les quelques exemples que l’on trouve chez [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22supporterisme%22%29&lang=en&suggest=0) nous renseignent mieux sur la signification du terme et comment le ***supporterisme*** (ou *supportérisme)* peut-être une version extrême de la ***[partisanerie](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/partisanerie)***, violente et intransigeante, que l’on pourra rapprocher du ***hooliganisme***, avec sans doute une tournure un peu plus française *(mes excuses à l’OQLF, qui [contesterait sans doute cette affirmation](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3582)).* La première citation ci-dessous, notamment, justifie assez bien *(à mes yeux du moins)* l’utilisation du suffixe *-isme* pour le concept défini par le terme, en ce sens que l’on y découvre qu’il existe une philosophie du supporter. Le fait d’être partisan n’est plus une passion plus ou moins involontaire, qui s’exprime, parfois bruyamment, par la joie ou la déception selon que gagne ou perd notre équipe ou notre championne, mais il devient plutôt un comportement volontaire, réfléchi et encodé, dont la valeur est susceptible d’être graduée par ceux qui en pratique l’art. On y distinguera l’ennemi, bien sûr, mais aussi les tièdes, les avachis, les paresseux, que l’on peut dès lors opposer aux vrais, aux durs de durs, à ceux qui ont le feu sacré.

Pour cerner la différence entre la ***partisanerie***, que le TLFi défini, certes, mais déclare [hapax](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/hapax) *(ce que Google News [dément avec vigueur](https://www.google.com/search?q=partisanerie&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi56Niuu87hAhXIm-AKHaV-DusQ_AUIECgD&biw=1378&bih=829), du moins pour le Québec)* et le ***supporterisme***, on pourra indiquer que la partisanerie peut facilement se contenter d’être mesquine et de mauvaise foi, et sans problème s’exprimer au niveau familial ou privé, là où le supporterisme s’exprimera davantage par des foules, entités plurielles qui démultiplient les puissances individuelles et peuvent se faire intimidantes, harassantes, et même très violentes en certains cas.

---

<sup>Les deux premières citations font usage des guillemets, ce qui n’aide certainement pas la cause de ce terme par ailleurs assez rare dans la littérature de langue française. Qui plus est, les guillemets sont utilisés à l’anglaise (“”)... Je mentionne simplement le fait pour que l’on ne croit pas que je suis celui qui les a introduit ci-dessous.</sup>

> Le **“supportérisme”** moderne, c’est-à-dire la spécialisation accentuée du rôle de supporter, la constitution d’enjeux au monde des supporters — être le plus spectaculaire, le plus fort, voire le plus violent —, peut se mettre en relation avec le nouveau statut de la jeunesse, un âge marqué par l’expérimentation plus que par l’identification. L’allongement des études, les formes d’entrée dans la vie active, les transformations des relations entre sexes et les formes d’organisation familiale sont marqués du sceau de l’expérimentation. Le **“supportérisme”** en est une : s’éprouver, faire ses preuves, apprendre à gérer, exercer l’autorité, négocier, etc. Le **supportérisme** à travers sa mise en scène parle effectivement de la guerre, de la vie et de la mort, de la virilité, des collectifs. Il renvoie à l’horizon des jeunes gens, quand on doit apprendre à tenir sa place, à faire l’expérience de son statut d’homme. On le fait en accumulant des émotions, avec d’autres, en mettant des masques, ici par exemple, celui de la dureté.
>
> Le rituel du **“supportérisme”** apparaît comme une activité qui donne du sens à la vie d’individus en les intégrant dans un mouvement collectif, en les inscrivant dans une lignée historique — celle du club qu’ils soutiennent — et en les séparant des autres, à la fois supporters adverses et supporters moins fervents qu’eux. Mais plus que la manifestation d’un collectif préexistant, le rituel du **“supportérisme”** peut souvent apparaître comme ce qui permet de réunir et de faire tenir un collectif problématique, menacé par les engagements des individus, qu’ils soient politiques, sociaux ou domestiques.
>   <sub>—Caisse nationale des allocations familiales (France), 1998</sub>
>
> Les drames de Schefield et du Heysel, les débordements des supporters du PSG, autant d’événements qui transforment le spectacle sportif en un problème social majeur. Pour comprendre la violence qui s’affiche dans les stades, Patrick Mignon analysera les causes du développement du **“supportérisme”** extrême et du “hooliganisme”, en France et en Grande Bretagne.
>   <sub>—Fédération française de handball, 1994</sub>
>
> Qu’est-ce qui fait vibrer les spectateurs d’un match de football ? Comment expliquer l’intensité de leurs réactions affectives ? Cet ouvrage nous éclaire en proposant une analyse précise des deux principaux registres émotifs du public de football. L’un prend sa source dans la dramatique du match, et n’exerce pleinement son effet que si le spectateur est supporter d’une équipe. L’autre est lié à la beauté qui se dégage de certaines actions de jeu quels qu’en soient les signataires. L’étude évite le manichéisme en montrant que ces deux types d’émotions contradictoires coexistent pourtant, chez beaucoup de spectateurs. Une coexistence où la force de chacune des tendances antagonistes varie, notamment, selon l’appartenance socio-culturelle des individus.
>
> Dans une seconde partie, faits à l’appui, l’auteur démontre que le milieu du football (dirigeants, entraineurs, joueurs, journalistes) active le **supportérisme** au détriment de la beauté du jeu. Il dégage, en particulier, l’idéologie qui domine dans ce milieu et qui rend les joueurs bien peu exigeants sur le choix des moyens pour parvenir à leurs fins. L’essai ne se termine pas pour autant sur une note totalement pessimiste. Au terme de son livre, l’auteur rappelle que la pratique du meilleur jeu possible reste le plus sûr moyen d’obtenir des résultats durables à condition que l’arbitrage en garantisse l’expression.
>   <sub>—Fédération sportive et gymnique du travail (France), 2001</sub>

Comment: Le TLFi dit de manière laconique « action de supporter » puis cite _Le Monde_ : « Le « supporterisme » est un comportement social qui engage l'individu, y compris dans son corps: lui aussi, il « fait le déplacement ». [...] ». Je trouvais ça transcendantal à souhait. L'état extrême c'est peut-être en effet ça la différence, l'extrémisme du support. Mais est-ce une action, un comportement, un jugement ou un simple constat. Les citations sont bien intéressantes !